# Why is my button onclick function with a confirm not popping up?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button link that looks like this in the HTML source:

```
<button  onclick="ewAttestConfirm('19')">Cert</button>
```

On the same page I have the following script defined. I want to redirect if the user click OK in the confirm popup. But nothing pops up when I click on the button. Any idea why?

(I tried to format the script nicer, but if I try putting the `window.location.assign` line on a separate line the editor here won't let me format it.)

```
<script>function ewAttestConfirm(idx) {
var r = confirm("Click OK to attest that you viewed this entire program.");
if (r == true) {window.location.assign("https://example.com/ewAttestToHoursAndRedirectToCert/?idx=idx")}
}
</script>
```

Comment: in button tag  add this.  type=“button”

Comment: Instead of r==true try just r like this if(r) { //your code }

Comment: Is your button inside any form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your javascript function should be like this,

```
function ewAttestConfirm(idx) {
  var r = confirm("Click OK to attest that you viewed this entire program.");
  if (r) {
    window.location.assign("https://example.com/ewAttestToHoursAndRedirectToCert/?idx="+idx);
  }
}
```

your variable *idx* should not be inside the string.And you can check the value true just by *if(variableName)*

you can see the working example below,

https://jsbin.com/ritikivave/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that idx needs to be outside the quotes. I modified that part with your suggestion: `if (r) {window.location.assign("https://newdev.edweb.net/ewAttestToHoursAndRedirectToCert/?idx=" + idx)}` but unfortunately that still doesn't help the conform itself pop up. Nothing happens if I click on the button.

Comment: That can't be. Try the method i have written above. I will attach a working link. Check that

Comment: I see the problem. My example was not complete. The message in my confirm was actually split into two lines using \n (as suggested by w3schools). That caused the function itself to break. So the popup does, in fact, work now. Thank you for your help and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Doug, can you edit your question so others can see what your actual issue was?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>function ewAttestConfirm(idx) {

if (window.confirm("Click OK to attest that you viewed this entire program."))
 {
window.location.assign("https://google.com)
}
}
</script>
```

This code will work